# Gsheets Apps script: Make a copy of a Spreadsheet in a specific folder of Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't find the solution:

**Pseudocode**

```
   Create Spreadsheet 'Spreadsheet_B' in folder 'myfolder'

   Paste copy of 'Spreadsheet_A' into 'myfolder'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id of the destination folder");
var copyFile=DriveApp.getFileById("id of the Spreadsheet you want to make the copy ");
folder.makeCopy("name of the new spreadSheet",copyFile);
```

[Where to find the 'id' of a folder and/or a Spreadsheet in Gdrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EztAa.jpg)